# Can we use std crates in benchmarking?

Tags: benchmarking, benchmark

For benchmarking I can see a need to use random number generators for maybe verification of a random storage or such. Do we have utilities provided by the `frame_benchmarking` framework itself or is it possible to bring in `std` dependencies for benchmarking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benchmarks compile to WASM and can thereby not access `std`.

Now in most cases it is enough to use a deterministic pseudorandom source like the output of a cryptographic hash. You can easily do this by defining a seed and recursively calling `Blake2` on it to generate as much "random" data as needed.
This has the advantage of being deterministic - benchmarks should always be deterministic for reproducibility.
But in general; `std` crates and hardware random number generators are not accessible.

(There *could* be a way to speparate the benchmarking setup from the actual execution, and thereby allow `std` in the setup phase, but it is just an idea - not anything that will be implemented any time soon.)